# How to add ListBox Items in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

**how do I add items to a listbox control by using  < ListBox.ItemTemplate> ?**

here is the xaml part:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ListBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Label Content="???????" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and here is the code for adding items:

```vb
private sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
ListBox1.Items.Add("Hello World")
End Sub
```

if I click on the buton1, a list item will be added with "??????" - I need to replace the "?????" with {Binding} or something so it can get the value correct value from button1_click ("Hello World")

Comment: Exactly, Content="{Binding}" should yield the desired result. Did you try and it failed? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just replace it with `{Binding}`, that alone should do it.

(`{Binding}` binds to the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) and the `DataContext` of the `ItemTemplate` will be the respective item, if the item is a simple string as in your example that will do, if it is a complex data object you will want to specify a [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) to bind to a property of the item)

Comment: I thought Binding is for Database Binding only. But {Binding} works, thanks! :)

Comment: @qxxx: [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) has nothing to do with databases, you can also bind between UI-elements for example.